# Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f (x+xy+f(y) )= (f(x)+ \frac 12 )\ (f(y)+ \frac 12 \ ).$

Tags: functional-equations

Find all functions $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that 
$$f\left (x+xy+f(y) \right )=\left (f(x)+ \frac 12 \right )\left (f(y)+ \frac 12 \right ).$$
for every $x,y \in \mathbb R$.

**My work so far:**

1) $y=-1$:
$$f(f(-1))=\left(f(x)+\frac 12 \right ) \cdot \left(f(-1)+\frac 12 \right ).$$
So, if $f(-1) \not = -\frac 12$ that $f=const$ ($c=(c+1/2)^2$ - contradiction)

So, $f(-1)=-\frac 12$.

2) $x=0$:
$$f(f(y))=\left(f(0)+\frac 12 \right ) \cdot \left(f(y)+\frac 12 \right ).$$
$y=0$
$$f(x+f(0))=\left(f(0)+\frac 12 \right ) \cdot \left(f(x)+\frac 12 \right )$$

Comment: I was able to establish that $f(x)=x+\frac 12$ for every $x,y \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: I tried to prove that $g(x)=f(x)-(x+\frac 12)=0$- is identically zero

Comment: I try substituting the type  $x=y=0$; $y=-1$; $y=0$,...

Comment: Could you develop a little more? You can edit your question to include your thoughts.

Comment: later I will do it

Comment: Here is a full solution not restricted to rationals or continous functions only: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h377568p2085522

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From $f(-1) = -\frac{1}{2}$ we obtain
$$ f \left( - \frac{1}{2} \right) = f (f (-1)) = 0.$$
So by choosing $y= - \frac{1}{2}$ we obtain
$$f\left( \frac{1}{2} x \right) = f\left(x - \frac{1}{2} x  + f\left( - \frac{1}{2} \right) \right) = \frac{1}{2} f(x) + \frac{1}{4}.$$
So $f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.
Choosing $y=0$ gives
$$f\left(x + \frac{1}{2}\right)=f(x) + \frac{1}{2}.$$
Combining this gives for $x= \frac{z}{2^n}$ with $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{2}$.
Now, if $f$ is continuous, we have $f(x) =x + \frac{1}{2}$ as the Dyadic numbers are dense on the real line.

However, $f$ does not need to be continuous, but for $x= \frac{m}{n}$ with $m,n \neq 0$ and $y=n-1$ we have
$$m+n = f \left( x+xy + f(y) \right) = n f(x) + \frac{n}{2}$$
and so 
$$f \left( \frac{m}{n} \right) = \frac{2m+n}{2n} = \frac{m}{n} + \frac{1}{2}.$$
So for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ we have $f(q) = q + \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Continuoty of $f$ is not required

Comment: Then I have to think about non-rational $x$ for a while. But you can at least show that for rational $x$, $f(x) =x + \frac{1}{2}$.